# System.Drawing.Common not working correctly in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, drawing, right-to-left

Please consider this code:

```
public static Stream WatermarkIt(Stream originalFile, Stream watermarkFile, string text1, string text2)
{
    var original = Image.FromStream(originalFile);
    var watermark = Image.FromStream(watermarkFile);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(original))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(watermark, new Point());
        var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback);
        graphics.DrawString(text1, new Font("FreeSans", 50), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 127, 127, 127)), new Rectangle(0, 200, original.Width, original.Height));
        format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap | StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft | StringFormatFlags.NoFontFallback, new CultureInfo("fa-IR").LCID);
        graphics.DrawString(text2, new Font("FreeSans", 50), new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 127, 127, 127)), new Rectangle(0, 400, original.Width, original.Height), format);
    }
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    original.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Now it's supposed to create this output, which correctly does, under Windows (.net core 2.2)

[image: The watermark output from windows]

But under Linux, the output is:

[image: The watermark output from Linux]

And if I change the second font to:

```
graphics.DrawString(text2, new Font("Noto Arabic", 50) ...
```

We get this:

[image: Improved watermark output from Linux]

Now a few observations:

1. The first watermark is read from a .png file, the color is gray with opacity 77, but under linux the text is interpreted as white with some transparency.
2. Right-To-Left text is not drawn correctly.

Is this because System.Drawing.Common is implemented partially in Linux, or is it possible to work around this problem?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, I switched to Skia + HarfBuzz. It worked pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

The System.Drawing.Common depend on libgdiplus library for rendering text, also this library have two engine (cairo and pango), unfortunately the default one (cairo) is not supporting Arabic.

So the option is not to download libgdiplus from apt-get or any package manager, because its already built with cairo engine, and you have to download source code and build it by your self.

First download the dependencies required:

```
sudo apt-get install libgif-dev autoconf libtool automake build-essential gettext libglib2.0-dev libcairo2-dev libtiff-dev libexif-dev
```

Download pango engine:

```
sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev
```

Then download the source code for libgdiplus:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus.git
```

Then build and install the library (go first insisde libgdiplus, i.e cd libgdiplus):

```
./autogen.sh --with-pango --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

Now you could run your code and you will see the arabic is rendered correctly.